# how to send null object (image) using axios to django

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, axios

I have a django backend that will save / remove image when receiving request from API. I have succesfully delete the saved image if i using swagger / postman to call the API (sending the parameter null object). But i can't get it work via Axios. 
The CURL from Swagger :

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IlNZU0FETUlOQFRSRUVTLkhBUlBBLkNPTSIsImV4cCI6MTUxNTAzNTU1MiwidXNlcl9uYW1lIjoiU1lTQURNSU5AVFJFRVMuSEFSUEEuQ09NIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MTQ5NDkxMDR9.oz3_2fGKlOCesmU_RmSRJZOifZeFFQO1nwAWzyD6BYc' 
-d '{ \ 
 "menu_type": 255,  \ 
 "icon": null, \ 
   "login_id": 1 \ 
 }'
```

My axios sample code :

```
formData.append('menu_type', 255)
formData.append('login_id', 1)
formData.append('icon', null)

const config = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
}

return new Promise(resolve => {
  axios.put(url + form.menu_uuid + "/", formData, config)
    .then(function (response) {
  resolve(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  resolve(error.response);
});
});
```

My request payload screenshot :
[image: My request payload screenshot]

Is there something that i missing that makes this axios request won't work ?

Answer (score 1):

i have succesfully deleted image at the API by using this axios code :

```
formData.append('icon', null, '')
```

maybe this answer will be useful for other person..

Comment: This did the trick for me, thanks! What does the last parameter (`''`) in the append function do?